# Using Arabic text in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, arabic

Why is is that this custom message:

```
[CustomMessages]
Arabic.NowInstalling=جار التنزيل %1
```

... is showing differently in Inno Setup?

[image]

The `%1` shows in different position.

Comment: The Inno Setup IDE probably does not handle BiDi languages correctly. Though if I save that string in Notepad, I can see that physically the `1%` is indeed at the end. So now the question is, who is wrong, Inno Setup or Notepad?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl NotePad ++ shows it at the start.